# Creating fields based on table relationship data

Tags: ms-access

I've taken up a personal project at work to create a software for our formulas. I need to make a components table that holds all the raw material data and a formula table that holds all the percentages. Since we may need to get rid of a component or add a new one, I need the second table to auto update if needed to add or remove the related field.

In the image I have an example of what it may look like (I'm new to database development). The table on the right are the components and the table on the left are the formulas. If I need to delete black from the table on the right, I want the table on the left to get rid of the Black field. And vice versa for adding new components.
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndUok.png)

Comment: Formulas table is not normalized structure. Tables cannot have a relationship with this design. Deleting records is seldom necessary nor justified. Usual approach is a field to flag record as "Inactive". Implementing a procedure that routinely changes db structure (such as add/remove fields) is poor design. Design changes in a deployed db should be rare.

Comment: Correction, Formulas table might be workable as is but there is still no relationship showing. What field in Components has key value for associated Formulas record? Can more than one component have same formula?

Comment: There are currently no relationships made, sorry I forgot to mean ruin that. No. Two formulas (IC items) can have the same components (cyan and magenta for example) with different values. So if I added another record, IC8 could have 80 cyan and 20 magenta. Edit: on mobile and not use to anything yet. The components are the base and the formulas combine the components. The value that would be added are percentages. But if I add let’s say a 9005 for Clear, I would need the formula table to add A clear field.

Comment: Then I return to my original assessment. Formulas table is not normalized and this is poor design. Not really seeing purpose of Components table.

Comment: In the end, there will be different colors from different companies that need to be recorded for shipments and tracking. For example: I would get a shipment of 9001 and need to track how much from that batch goes into an ink. So if I have 100 lbs of 9001 and I use 50 lbs to make IC5, the weight (a different table not shown or made yet) will need to update for inventory tracking.

Comment: The progression goes as follow: I get a shipment, I create a record that holds the component name, weight of component, a tag Id and a lot number. From there, i create a record for a formula that subtract weight from the component of a given tag ID and adds it to a new tag I’d with the formula name in the name value. I may not be explaining as clearly because this process is like second nature to me at this point so the flow is just there for me mentally. My apologies if this doesn’t clear things up fully.

Comment: Normally, balance of inventory would be calculated from transaction records, not 'updated' to a table. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: So after looking at the link and looking at other inventory and order information, I’ve realized that I should look at this as a store rather than formulas. My components are items and the formulas are “orders that can be changed before shipping” or something of that nature. Thank you so much.